# Keep getting The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: batch-file

Hello im having a bit of problem when trying to run this batch file

```
@echo off

rem ashton scotland

rem test file

cls

if exist C:\Users\ashton\Desktop\test\

echo the directory exists
```

can someone please guide me as to why im getting that error message thanks

Comment: @EliasBenevedes "The syntax of the command is incorrect" - it''s in the question title. Um yes - best put in the question body too, I'd agree.

Answer (score 3):

there is no command after if condition.Try this:

```
@echo off

rem ashton scotland

rem test file

cls

if exist "C:\Users\ashton\Desktop\test\" (

 echo the directory exists
)
```

or

```
@echo off

rem ashton scotland

rem test file

cls

if exist "C:\Users\ashton\Desktop\test\"  echo the directory exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Exist maches files or folders. This see's if a folder or not.

```
@Echo off
pushd %1 >nul 2>&1  
If errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 Echo %~nx1 is a folder
If errorlevel 1 Echo %~nx1 is not a folder
Popd

If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause


pause
```